# Referencing a computed property from a child in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

So I have a model:

```
// Parent View Model
GameViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, resultItemMapping, self);

    self.PlayerCount = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Results().length;
    });
};
```

And using these mappings it's children:

```
var resultItemMapping = {
    'Results': {
        key: function (resultItem) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(resultItem.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new ResultItemViewModel(options.data); 
        }
    }
};

// Child View Model
ResultItemViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, resultItemMapping, self);

    self.Points = ko.computed(function () {
        return (parent.PlayerCount);
    });
};
```

You can see that the Game View Model (parent) has a computed observable called PlayerCount (self.PlayerCount) and I can successfully bind this to my view and the amount increases / decreases accordinfly depending on the length of the Results (child) collection.

The problem lies with with the child computed observable called Points (self.Points). The controls when bound to it are always empty, and if I try and do something like `return (parent.PlayerCount * 10)` I always get `NaN` returned.

Ideally based on the player count, the result item points total should be `n * PlayerCount`.

Clearly what I've coded does not work correctly, but I do not get any console error messages. Is there a better method of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You should be passing the player count observable to the child.

Comment: But if the count changes i.e. a new result is added to the child collection, how would the player count that has been passed to the children originally get updated?

Comment: Pass the computed property, not just the current value.

Comment: Your computed is simply a read only observable that has a dependency on the Results observable array.

Comment: Could you expand on this more? I understand what you're suggesting and can sort of see where my thinking was wrong but I'm not 100% sure using my example on how I would pass it to the child. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using components? Pass the player count computed to the child's input params.

Comment: No - I don't think so, I'm still relatively new to KO. I'm using `ko.mapping.fromJS` to create my view model from my MVC view model. The only place I can see to pass the computed observable would be in the resultsItemMapping create function, but as the view model hasn't completed binding yet, the computed observable doesn't exist at that point. I checked in the debugger and at that point, only the view model properties from the MVC view model exist.

Comment: So are you saying that the child gets created before its parent? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: No. The ResultViewModel is created first it would seem as I can see all it's properties and values because I use `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, resultItemMapping, self);`. So at this point I have my view model populated with data from the server. I presume at that point it then runs `self.PlayerCount = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Results().length;
    });` which would explain why my computed property isn't available from the mapping function. This is why I presumed I would just be able to call something like `parent.PlayerCount` from the result view model.

Comment: When you say child, do you mean a child element or a subclass?

Comment: A subclass as in a result is a subclass of game. I've added more notes onto the answer from @Tomalak below.

Comment: Note that the word "child" already has a very different meaning in this domain. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy. [The mapping plugin provides the parent for you](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create):

```
var GameViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Results = ko.observableArray();    
    self.PlayerCount = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.Results().length;
    });

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, GameViewModel.mapping, self);    
};
GameViewModel.mapping = {
    Results: {
        key: function (resultItem) {
            return ko.unwrap(resultItem.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new ResultItemViewModel(options.data, options.parent); // <- here
        }
    }
};

var ResultItemViewModel = function (data, parent) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Points = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return parent.PlayerCount();
    });

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ResultItemViewModel.mapping, self);
};
ResultItemViewModel.mapping = {
    // I can't imagine you want the same mapping definition as in the GameViewModel
};
```

Note that I've made a few other subtle changes, most prominently using [pure computeds](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html). I also like to make the viewmodel properties explicit instead of depending entirely on the mapping plugin. This and prevents code from accessing properties that don't exist and generally makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you. This is basically what I tried to do with the help above. However, when you pass `options.parent` in the mapping, the PlayerCount doesn't exist on it. [See screen shot of debugger](http://i.imgur.com/OHYCg9L.png)

Comment: That's why I formulate the API of my view model explicitly, instead of letting the mapping plugin do it. In my very reduced example above, it works. `parent` is set to the `GameViewModel`, which means I get to access all of its properties.

Comment: Oh, defining all properties *before* you access them will help, of course. Do the mapping *after* the declaration of `PlayerCount`. See edited answer.

Comment: Yes. That is the answer! Thank you. I had also tried this before hand but had not set Results as an observable array and got errors in the console suggesting as much but didn't investigate further as I was going through @CrimsonChris help. Thank you both, I appreciate it.

Comment: Bootstrapping your viewmodels can be made a lot easier by getting used to a fixed order in which you do things. First define observables (with useful default values), then set up computed values, then subscriptions, then do your mapping. I also like to define instance methods on the prototype and static properties (like the mapping definition) on the constructor.